# Java Server Android client Wifi sending file, socket error

Tags: java, android, client-server

I have some problem with sending file from server (Desktop APP) to client (Android)....

Before send file, server send meta data like size of file, name etc.....

Server side send method:

```
private void sendPdfData(OutputStream os, File file) throws IOException {

    os.flush();
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    byte[] buffor = new byte[1024];
    long count = 0L;
    long size = file.length();
    int current = 0;   

    while (count < size) {  
        current = fis.read(buffor, 0, buffor.length);
        os.write(buffor, 0, current);
        count += current;
    }

    fis.close();
    os.flush();
}
```

Client side receive method:

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

    String pathToPdf = "";

    if (pdf.getLength() > 0) {

        InputStream is;

        try {
            byte b = 0;
            clientSocket.getOutputStream().write(b);
            is = clientSocket.getInputStream();
            pathToPdf = pathToExternalStorageFolder+pdf.getMeta().getName();
            pathToPdf = pathToPdf.replace(".\\", "/");
            pathToPdf = pathToPdf.replace("\\", "/");
            int size = pdf.getLength();
            byte[] buffor = new byte[1024];
            int current = 0;
            int count = 0;

            if (pdf.getMeta() != null) {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pathToPdf);

                while (count < size) {
                    current = is.read(buffor, 0, buffor.length);
                    fos.write(buffor, 0, current);
                    count += current;
                }
                fos.close();
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }    
    return pathToPdf;
}
```

Some random errors when sending file:

```
java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error

File size: 2317679
Sended: 44032
```

UPDATE 08.09.2013

I create desktop client app to check server app.
When I run server and client in NetBeans everything runs great, I use interface address (not lopback).
When I run client from jar I have issue: file list is null but on server side is not null and is not empty, when connect from android i get files list wtfigo - magic.

Answer (score 0):

"This error can occur when the local network system aborts a connection, such as when WinSock closes an established connection after data retransmission fails (receiver never acknowledges data sent on a datastream socket).".

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms832256.aspx

https://forums.oracle.com/thread/1691330

`Socket.close()` in one Thread while another is reading from or writing to that socket, results in an Exception being thrown since the socket was closed.

try adding `autoReconnect=true` to the jdbc connection string

Comment: Hmm, why U say it's a problem on jdbc side ? I use only server-client side connection based on sockets - don't use jdbc when sending file.
I can try this on linux.

Comment: I test under Linux but is not working. (same problem on Linux and Windows)